# Python 3 cannot import third party packages

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have Python version 3.5.2 and I have pip3, so I did

```
sudo pip3 install pyqt5
```

That got installed in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

However when I enter my python 3 interpreter and type

```
import PyQt5
```

it gives me an error that it can't find the module named PyQt5.

So I tried adding the /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages path to PYTHONPATH by doing

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

but that didn't fix anything. How do I make Python 3.5.2 detect PyQt5?

Comment: do `sudo pip3 install pyqt5` and test again

Comment: @George ah sorry, I forgot to mention that I did try sudo from the very start. I edited my question to portray that. All it says is "pyqt5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages"

Comment: try running `sudo -H pip3 install pyqt5` this time lets see what happens. Quite strange as I have successfully installed it on my system, also do `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` __before__ the `pips` command

Comment: Oh, I just noticed after doing `python 3 import site; site.getsitepackages()` that it only finds /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages, and it doesn't list the /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages that the actual modules are installed in. Do you think that might be my problem?

Comment: No shakes just redo!

Comment: @George hmm well I tried what you asked, but it still says `Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: sip in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from pyqt5)
` Maybe it's a site packages issue...

Comment: about the importation of __dist package__ I should think so.

Comment: okay, so inside the python 3 interpreter I did `import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages")
` and it was able to import PyQt5 after that. Do you know how to make python3 always do this without me needing to code it into every script?

Comment: I am not an expert on that but i think only native python libs can be used this way... but a template might make it easier

Comment: Okay. Also, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to George I slowly got to the answer. The root of the problem lies in that I installed my Python 3.5.2 version from a source rather than from the Ubuntu aptitude package manager.

Basically, if Python is installed from a source, then, to look for 3rd party packages, it uses `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages`, but if it was installed using `apt`, then Python looks in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`. This is to make sure that the several Python versions don't get tangled up. Here is another question that explains: [what is the difference between dist-packages and site-packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages).

**Solution:**

My Python3 installation was looking into site-packages and ignoring dist-packages, so I added a path file to make it look inside dist-packages as well.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
sudo vim dist-packages.pth
(Press i to go into insert mode inside Vim)
../dist-packages
:x (and Press Enter/Return)
```

Now when Python looks inside `/site-packages`, it finds `dist-packages.pth` which makes it go into `/dist-packages`.

**Other Solution:**

[Someone else](https://superuser.com/questions/247620/how-to-globally-modify-the-default-pythonpath-sys-path) had a problem exactly the reverse of mine, where their Python installation only looked inside `/dist-packages`, so they used the exact same method as above except instead of making a `dist-packages.pth` file (containing `../dist-packages`) inside `/site-packages`, they made a `site-packages.pth` file (containing `../site-packages` inside `/dist-packages`.

**Check if it worked:**

The easy way to check if this worked is to go into your Python interpreter and print sys.path. It should now contain both package paths:

```
charliebrown@playground:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 19 2016, 02:36:25) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys; print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/local/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5',     '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/plat-linux', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages']
```

I hope this helps someone one day...